# Qt Accidental activation of dragLeaveEvent，what should I do?

Tags: c++, qt

I have a `QPushButton` on a `QScrollArea`, the parent of the `QPushButton` is the `QScrollArea`. I drag the object to the `QScrollArea` and then to the `QPushButton` which always activates the `dragLeaveEvent` of the `QScrollArea`, I don't want this function to activate, what should I do?

Comment: If the push button accepts drag events (and is supposed to) there is not much you can do about. Though, you can install an event filter which detects this and handles it early (so it won't be passed to the scroll area).
Though, drag & drop (at least on Windows) is very special. I once tried to handle keyboard keys while in drag&drop. (It was very important for me to support it.) I finally ended up to write my own drag manager which plainly filters mouse events and "simulates" (emulates?) drag & drop...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for your replies, I have solved the problem.
The method is very simple, just set the parent of the QPushButton to QScrollArea::widget() and it's solved.